# Pandas - Behaviour of DateTime x-axis when using secondary y-axis not as expected (what am I doing wrong?)

Tags: python, datetime, plot, pandas

I'm trying to plot two dataframes over each other, both with a DateTimeIndex using two secondary axis. First how I load the data:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('SmartIce_20140927_all_voltage.csv', encoding='latin1', parse_dates=['DateTime'], index_col='DateTime')
df2 = pd.read_csv('SmartIce_20140927_temperature.csv', encoding='latin1', parse_dates=['UTC_Time'], index_col='UTC_Time')
```

And check the data output:

```js
In [7]: df1.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 10302 entries, 2014-09-27 16:58:54 to 2014-09-29 11:56:20
Data columns (total 5 columns):
DLPIO20_AIN0    10302 non-null float64
DLPIO20_AIN1    10302 non-null float64
DLPIO20_AIN2    10302 non-null float64
DLPIO20_AIN3    10302 non-null float64
DLPIO20_AIN4    10302 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(5)

In [8]: df1.head()
Out[8]: 
                     DLPIO20_AIN0  DLPIO20_AIN1  DLPIO20_AIN2  DLPIO20_AIN3  \
DateTime                                                                      
2014-09-27 16:58:54      0.004883      3.642578      3.696289      4.980469   
2014-09-27 16:59:09      0.004883      3.637695      3.637695      4.985352   

In [12]: df2.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 2580 entries, 2014-09-27 16:53:00 to 2014-09-29 11:52:00
Data columns (total 3 columns):
Sample      2580 non-null int64
Temp        2580 non-null float64
DateTime    2580 non-null object
dtypes: float64(1), int64(1), object(1)

In [14]: df2.head()
Out[14]: 
                     Sample   Temp         DateTime
UTC_Time                                           
2014-09-27 16:53:00       1 -15.44  9/27/2014 14:23
2014-09-27 16:54:00       2 -14.61  9/27/2014 14:24
```

Now when I try to plot:

```
df1.DLPIO20_AIN4.plot()
df2.Temp.plot(secondary_y=True, style='g')
```

I get two images (I can't attach images because I need ten reputation). Image one has a time axis that is just hours (formatted for example 18:00:00 at a diagonal). Image two, which I wasn't expecting, has a time axis formatted as hours and underneath the day (which I prefer). I was expecting to get one plot layed over the other plot. I've played around with various things but I'm not sure what I should be doing to fix it, nor how to proceed. I believe the DatetimeIndexes are identical, ...or at least I understand I have set them up like that.

Comment: You're creating two instances of images. In order to get the effect you want, in general, your base image(s) should contain the default graphics (basic axis, grid lines, etc...). Your 'overlaying' image should have a transparent background and all of the data-specific graphics (axis labels, plots, etc...). These should be combined into *one* instance of an image and that is what you should be trying to output. Good luck.

Comment: A little hard to get through the formatting, but I think that looks like the right idea. Modifying your base image instance with your data specific graphics as needed, all in one instance. Does it now work the way you wanted it too?

Comment: Thanks for your response ouflak. I did some more reading and used this                                                                   fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.plot(df1.DLPIO20_AIN4, 'g-')
ax2.plot(df2.Temp, 'b-')


ax1.set_xlabel('X data')
ax1.set_ylabel('Y1 data', color='g')
ax2.set_ylabel('Y2 data', color='b')

plt.show()                                                                       Which got me two overlaid plots but now the x-zxis is just an index. I have lost the benefit of the Pandas DateTime features.

Comment: I also went back to the Pandas example in the documentation and found I couldn't get that working. More experimentation required.

Comment: Keep at it. I think you are on the right track.

Comment: Just one point, if you do find a solution, it would be nice to have that posted here as it may help future Pandites who run into a similar issue.